# config products out of stock option controlling

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

I have one doubt magento below are the my question

```
Configurable Product

Manage Stock => Yes; Use Config Settings
Stock Availability => In Stock
Simple Product 1

Manage Stock => Yes; Use Config Settings
Stock Availability => Out of Stock
Quantity => 0
Simple Product 2

Manage Stock => Yes; Use Config Settings
Stock Availability => Out of Stock
Quantity => 1
Simple Product 3

Manage Stock => Yes; Use Config Settings
Stock Availability => Out of Stock
Quantity => 0
```

all simple products are out of stock.

but config product showing instock. it can't update dynamically when associated products are out of stock.

all simple products are out of stock.

but config product showing in stock. it can't update dynamically when associated products are out of stock.